# Filling and emptying a tank in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to create a model for filling and emptying a tank in R using tidyverse. It's a little more complicated, but for my minimum reproducible example, let's just say I have a tank and there is a control variable. When that variable is below a certain value, let's add to the tank. When that variable is above a certain value, let's empty the tank a little bit. There's a rate we can fill and empty the tank and the tank has a capacity.

How do I add a variable to the dataframe to keep track of the tanks level, taking into account the flow and not having a value below zero and above the tank's capacity. Below is my attempt:

```
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(55)

rate <- 10
tank_cap <- 500

model <- data_frame(
  id = 1:100,
  control = ceiling(runif(100, 0, 10)),
) %>%
  mutate(
    flow = case_when(
      control < 3 ~ rate,
      control > 7 ~ -rate,
      TRUE ~ 0
    ),
    tank_level = lag(tank_level, 1) + flow
  )
```

Comment: Perhaps `cumsum`? You don't use `tank_cap` and you don't define `tank_level`, are they supposed to be linked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need `cumsum` with combination of `pmin` and `pmax` to account for `tank_level` range of `0 to tank_cap` -

```
set.seed(55)

rate <- 10
tank_cap <- 500

model <- data_frame(
  id = 1:100,
  control = ceiling(runif(100, 0, 10)),
  tank_level = 0
) %>%
  mutate(
    flow = case_when(
      control < 3 ~ rate,
      control > 7 ~ -rate,
      TRUE ~ 0
    )
    ,tank_level = pmin(pmax(cumsum(tank_level + flow), 0), tank_cap)
  )

head(model, 12)

# A tibble: 12 x 4
      id control tank_level  flow
   <int>   <dbl>      <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1       2         10    10
 2     2       9          0   -10
 3     3       2         10    10
 4     4      10          0   -10
 5     5       2         10    10
 6     6       6         10     0
 7     7       3         10     0
 8     8       7         10     0
 9     9       7         10     0
10    10       7         10     0
11    11       6         10     0
12    12       1         20    10
```